# How to disable a session in passport?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-twitter

Im trying to disable a session in passport.js but it doesnt work, i still need to add express-session.

code:

```
  router.get('/twitter', function(req, res, next){

  passport.authenticate('twitter', {session: false}, function(err, user, info){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    if(user){
      var token = createToken(user);
      return res.json({token: token});
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

How do i change the default session of passport in this code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that sessions are required for OAuth 1.0 (the version twitter uses). OAuth 1.0 requires a per-transaction "secret" which is exchanged before the redirect and verified after the redirect. This secret is stored in the session, hence why sessions are required for any OAuth 1.0-based strategies.

In other words, you can't set the session to false while using the twitter strategy.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you just log the user out using req.logout(); .